# Difference between int *x[] and int (*x)[]?

Tags: c, required, lvalue

My teacher asked me to find out the difference.Can anyone help me with this?
Actually I know first part of is array of pointer but what the second part means.Both are not same because I tried a code for this:

```
i = 1;
j = 2;
x[0] = &i;
x[1] = &j;
```

got an error saying "lvalue required"

Comment: Which language are you referring to? C?

Answer (score 8):

When in doubt, consult [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/):

```
int (*x)[]
declare x as pointer to array of int

int *x[]
declare x as array of pointer to int
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int *x[3];
```

Here `x` is an array of 3 pointers to `int`.

```
int (*x)[3];
```

Here `x` is a pointer to an array of three `int`s.

Here's a usage example of both:

```
int* arrayOfPointers[3];
int x, y, z;
arrayOfPointers[0] = &x;
arrayOfPointers[1] = &y;
arrayOfPointers[2] = &z;

int (*pointerToArray)[3];
int array[3];
pointerToArray = &array;
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Work your way through starting near the variable name "x" and finishing up with type, keeping in mind [Operator Precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B). Meaning, anything in ()'s and []s before *'s.

```
     x[] -- x is an array
    *x[] -- x is an array of pointers
int *x[] -- x is an array of pointers to ints

(*x)        -- x is a pointer
(*x) []     -- x is a pointer to an array
int (*x)[]  -- x is a pointer to an array of type int
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, remember that C declarations reflect the type of an *expression* (i.e., declaration mimics use).

For example, if you have a pointer to an integer, and you want to access the integer value being pointed to, you *dereference* the pointer with the unary `*` operator, like so:

```
int x = *p;
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`, so the declaration of the pointer `p` is

```
int *p;
```

Now suppose you have an array of pointers to `int`; to access any specific integer value, you subscript into the array to find the correct pointer and dereference the result:

```
int x = *a_of_p[i];
```

The subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than the unary `*` operator, so the expression `*a_of_p[i]` is parsed as `*(a_of_p[i])`; we're dereferencing the result of the expression `a_of_p[i]`.  Since the type of the *expression* `*a_of_p[i]` is `int`, the declaration of the array is

```
int *a_of_p[N];
```

Now flip that around; instead of an array of pointers to `int`, you have a pointer to an array of `int`.  To access a specific integer value, you must dereference the pointer *first* and then subscript the result:

```
int x = (*p_to_a)[i];
```

Since `[]` has higher precedence than `*`, we must use parentheses to force the grouping of operators so that the subscript is applied to the *result* of the expression `*p_to_a`.  Since the type of the expression `(*p_to_a)[i]` is `int`, the declaration is

```
int (*p_to_a)[N];
```

When you see a declaration that looks a bit hairy, start with the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering that `[]` and `()` have higher precedence than `*`, so `*a[]` is an array of pointer, `(*a)[]` is a pointer to an array, `*f()` is a function returning a pointer, and `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function:

```
      x       -- x
    (*x)      -- is a pointer
    (*x)[N]   -- to an N-element array 
int (*x)[N]   -- of int

     x        -- x
     x[N]     -- is an N-element array
    *x[N]     -- of pointer
int *x[N];    -- to int.
```

Answer (score 0):

`int(*x)[ARRAY_SIZE]` interprets as a pointer to an array of integers.